# Steps for customizing Liferay control panel theme

Tags: themes, liferay, control-panel

Can anyone please tell me how to customize **Liferay control-panel theme** in Liferay 6.2 (step-by-step)?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13225826

Comment: @Saha searching google with this same query would have provided you this link as first result!